# Phantom error in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I converted all categorical string values to numerical,also, I am sure that there is no null values.
**My dataset:**
https://www.kaggle.com/murderaccountability/homicide-reports/data
**My code**:

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
database_df = pd.read_csv("database.csv",low_memory=False,usecols=  ['State','Year','Month','Crime Type','Crime Solved','Victim Sex','Victim Age','Victim Race','Perpetrator Sex','Perpetrator Age','Perpetrator Race','Relationship','Weapon','Victim Count','Perpetrator Count'])
database_df.replace({'Victim Sex':mappingGender,'Perpetrator    
Sex':mappingGender},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'Crime Solved':mappingCrimeSolved},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'Victim Race':mappingRace,'Perpetrator  
Race':mappingRace},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'Relationship':mappingRelation},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'Weapon':mappingWeapon},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'Crime Type':mappingCrimeType},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'State':mappingState},inplace=True)
database_df.replace({'Month':mappingMonth},inplace=True)

X, y = database_df.iloc[:,:-1], database_df.iloc[:, -1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.3, random_state=42) 
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=8)
knn.fit(X_train,y_train)
knn.predict(X_test)
```

** I get this error**
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

**Please, I need a help!There is no string pointed in error**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You code [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and print some relevant data in the except suite to get an idea of what is happening.. You should always post the complete Traceback and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @wwii Ok,thank you